# Why can't I install setuptools on my Centos 6 VPS?

Tags: python, setuptools, centos6

I'm trying to install setuptools for Python2.7 on a Centos 6 VPS with Digital Ocean using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4). When I reach the step where you "Intall setuptools using the Python we've installed (2.7.6)", I get this error:

```
[username@hotsname setuptools-1.4.2]$ python2.7 setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-1111.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Now, I previously followed [instructions on the same digital ocean community site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/initial-server-setup-with-centos-6) to give the user executing the above root privileges. When I try to use sudo to do this task, I get:

```
[username@hostname setuptools-1.4.2]$ sudo python2.7 setup.py install
[sudo] password for username: 
sudo: python2.7: command not found
```

So I'm a little confused. I feel like I'm probably missing something simple. Digital Ocena was unable to provide further support on this. I've worked with virtualenv for a long time and am familiar with what to do once I get it installed, I'm just stuck here as it's my first time setting up a Centos host. Can you tell what I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you do just `sudo python` (withouth 2.7)? What does `sudo python --version` say?

Comment: CentOS can be quite silly. Try changing to root user instead of just sudo. `sudo su`, and then try just running `python2.7 setup.py install` again. You also might have to close and reopen your SSH connection just to make sure the environment has been updated properly. Edit: It also looks like that page assumes you are running all commands as the root user.

Comment: @user1781026, sudo python --version says: Python 2.6.6, so I'll try CasualDemon's idea first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to root user did the trick. Thanks CasualDemon.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, if you'd like to install setuptools & pip easily, you can run this file with your python interpreter:

[get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

You made need administrator (root) privileges for installing it to your system python (e.g `sudo python get-pip.py`.

Afterwards you can upgrade pip and/or setuptools through e.g:

```
$ pip install -U setuptools
$ pip install -U pip
```

I recommend for most python development you only install setuptools, pip, and virtualenv as root (or purely virtualenv, if you're being conservative). After, you can use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) virtual environments to create isolated python environments which don't need to install to the system python or affect its installed packages. That way no other python (and/or `pip` invocations) needs to be run as root.